# Character for character replace() using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, textarea

I'm trying to create a character for character translator similar to Google Translate but for Chars, kind of like a decoder. This is what I have so far, but I'm stuck near the last line of JavaScript. I don't know what I need to put for the latter portion of the replace() method with the `replacement` variable

```
<form>

    <textarea class="form-control" id="englishform" onkeyup="replacer('englishform')" onkeydown="replacer('englishform')" placeholder="Enter English" rows="15"></textarea><br />
</form>
<form>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="albhedform" placeholder="Enter Al Bhed" rows="15"></textarea>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function replacer(e){
    var replacement = ['y', 'p', 'l', 't', 'a', 'v', 'k', 'r', 'e', 'z', 'g', 'm', 's', 'h', 'u', 'b', 'x', 'n', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'j', 'f', 'q', 'o', 'w']; 
    var english = document.getElementById(e);
    var albhed = document.getElementById('albhedform');
    albhed.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, replacement/*here is the issue */); 
}
</script>
```

So the issue is with the latter part of the replace() method. I can't seem to get the regex brackets to be replaced letter for letter using `"c => replacement[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]"`

```
albhed.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacement[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]
```

Can somebody explain what needs to be fixed?

Comment: So you want Char to be replaced with corresponding ASCII??

Comment: That line with `.charCodeAt(0)-97` worked for me once I added the closing `)`. What is an example of input for which it doesn't work?

Comment: Is the last snippet the **_exact_** code you're trying to use?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb, I'm trying to use that last snippet with a closing parenthesis as follows: `albhed.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => replacement[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]);` and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @nnnnnn any text I enter is not displaying in the `albhedform` textarea and it doesn't translate either. my goal is to get `'a' = 'y',
'b' = 'p',
'c' = 'l',
'd' = 't',
'e' = 'a',
'f' = 'v',
'g' = 'k',
'h' = 'r',
'i' = 'e',
'j' = 'z',
'k' = 'g',
'l' = 'm',
'm' = 's',
'n' = 'h',
'o' = 'u',
'p' = 'b',
'q' = 'x',
'r' = 'n',
's' = 'c',
't' = 'd',
'u' = 'i',
'v' = 'j',
'w' = 'f',
'x' = 'q',
'y' = 'o',
'z' = 'w'`

Comment: Here is a js fiddle that shows the code not working https://jsfiddle.net/gy85060q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code on the fiddle is perfectly fine. You just need to change the language to Babel + JSX and remove the script tags in the JavaScript area. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xq0jcnmh/) doing just that. Just change your JavaScript as below

```
function replacer(e){
    var replacement = ['y', 'p', 'l', 't', 'a', 'v', 'k', 'r', 'e', 'z', 'g', 'm', 's', 'h', 'u', 'b', 'x', 'n', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'j', 'f', 'q', 'o', 'w']; 
    var english = document.getElementById(e);
    var albhed = document.getElementById('albhedform');
    albhed.value = english.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => 
    replacement[c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97]);
}
```

This is mostly because arrow functions are not yet completely supported in browsers.

Comment: You say that, but if it still doesn't work, it's not fine. Thanks for the effort